# Where is the remote-exec script located in case of crash?

Tags: terraform

My terraform playbook failed with the following error :

```
Error: error executing "/tmp/terraform_911394309.sh": wait: remote command exited without exit status or exit signal
```

I got no idear what the error was, where it is, what command was executed...

**Where is the /tmp/terraform_911394309.sh script ?** So that maybe I can see what failed !
Obvioulsy its not in `/tmp/`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... Its stupid but it did not stroke me at first.

Its indeed in `/tmp/` but not on the host. Its on the target on which the script was meant to be executed...